# Updading UILabel in real time in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am trying to update UILabel text inside handler of queryPedometerDataFromDate(..) method. Update on UILabel reflects after 20 or 25 seconds. But I see println() output almost in real time. Is there any way to make it quicker?
If I update text of UILabel outside this handler, then again it updates in real time.

```
        pedoman.queryPedometerDataFromDate(yester, toDate: now) {
        (data:CMPedometerData!, errr:NSError!) -> Void in
        //Below statement take 20 to 30 second to reflect on UILabel
        self.StringSteps.text = data.numberOfSteps.stringValue
        //Below statement prints on Output in real time.
        println("Number of Steps \(data.numberOfSteps)")
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to update UILabel on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
self.StringSteps.text = data.numberOfSteps.stringValue
});
```

Comment: Sorry! I accidentally wrote  the other queue. I meant Main Queue.

Comment: Thanks man, worked like a charm. I believe that control symbol is typo too.

Answer (score 3):

The block you supplied to the `queryPedometerDataFromDate:toDate:withHandler:` method gets executed in a serial queue, not on the main thread. You should make all of your UI updates from the main thread. You can do this by using GCD like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
   self.StringSteps.text = data.numberOfSteps.stringValue
})
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
self.StringSteps.text = data.numberOfSteps.stringValue}
```